# Can I access the users data on django admin while using django-allauth?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-allauth, user-administration

I am new, first question..
I have configured django-allauth on a django project. It is working fine front end.
When I access the Django-admin interface with the superuser, I can access all sorts of things that django-allauth as added like :
-accounts
-social accounts
-sites
I cannot access to the normal user data, the one which is in a table called 'campfire-users' in the db (campfire being the name of the application).
Normally it appears in a group called 'authentication and authorisation" where you find 'groups' and 'users'.
I have also noticed that the name of the top level app which normally appears in the top left of the admin interface is not appearing :  'application_name ADMIN' becomes ADMIN.
Any clue ?
[the admin interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0bbg.png)

Answer (score 2):

I finally get the answer :
Having created a custom User class, I did not register it into 'admin.py'.
I had to edit 'admin.py' and add this :

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import User

admin.site.register(User)
```

Then the users appeared on admin interface. Still one pointto solve : why the name of the application is not appearing?